# redirect https in *.conf file

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

On the WWW I can find a lot of info for redirecting http to https. But this isn't exactly what I need.

I need to redirect on old dns name to a new one, http and https. Can somebody point me in the correct direction. I prefer to work with virtual host configuration it is easier then Mod_Rewrite.

Every time when I add an extra Virtual host 443 and restart the APACHE2 service the config can't be loaded.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the config can't be loaded you might have an error in it. Check in /var/log/apache.

```
ls -arlt
```

in the log folder will give you at the bottom of the list the last messages.
It should be error.log.
You can run

```
tail -f error.log
```

to see what is happening when you restart.

If everything is fine, you should have in thew old domain config file a line like :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com
```

which is the proper way to redirect one domain tot another, with respect to SEO.

Comment: Hello, sorry in my delay for answering you. There was an error in the config file, this because I put two configs together. I created a second conf file and redirected the original file and it works smoothly. Thanks for your help.